# Is there an azure policy to deny Storage account deployment to ensure soft delete in json custom policy?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, soft-delete, azure-policy, retention

I have tried these two policy aliases which didn't work

```
 "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/deleteRetentionPolicy.enabled",
            # "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/deleteRetentionPolicy.enabled"
            "equals": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
      }
    }
```

},

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38762671-azure-policy-to-deny-storage-account-creation-when

Answer (score 0):

No, currently, there is no such policy for that.

There is already an [user feedback here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38762671-azure-policy-to-deny-storage-account-creation-when), please up-vote it. Let's wait the team to implement this feature.